# Show records from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need show record from database. But I have a error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Login'

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dodaj Pracownika</legend>

    @foreach (var pr in ViewBag.dane)
        {
            <div>Login: @pr.Login</div>

              <div>Imie: @pr.imie</div> 

        }
</fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult detail(int LoginID)
    {
        var user = (from p in baza.Logowanies
                    join d in baza.uzytkowniks on p.LoginID equals d.LoginID 
                    where LoginID == p.LoginID
                    select new { p.Login, p.Haslo, p.konto, d.imie, d.nazwisko, d.pesel, d.nip, d.telefon, d.adres_zamieszkania, d.email }).ToList();
        ViewBag.dane = user;
        return View();
    }
```

It was working when I put records from one table in database (without join in query). But now is something wrong.

Using

> @grid.GetHtml

everything is allright.

**//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

**EDIT**

I make edits and now I have:

View:

```
@model Restauracja.Models.pracownikModel
 @foreach (dynamic pr in ViewBag.dane)
        {
            <div>Login: @pr.Login</div>

             <div>Imie: @pr.imie</div>
```

Model:

```
public class pracownikModel 
    {
         public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
         public uzytkownikModel uzytkownikModle { get; set; }
       public pracownikModel() {
           LoginModel = new LoginModel();
           uzytkownikModle = new uzytkownikModel();
       }
    }

    public class LoginModel 
    {
        [Required]
        public string Użytkownik { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Hasło { get; set; }

        public string Konto { get; set; }

    }

    public class uzytkownikModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string imie { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string nazwisko { get; set; }
           . . . . .

    }
```

And Controller:

```
public ActionResult Kontakt()
        {
            bazaDataContext baza = new bazaDataContext();
            var user = (from p in baza.Logowanies
                        join d in baza.uzytkowniks on p.LoginID equals d.LoginID
                        select new pracownikModel{p.Login, d.imie}).ToList();

            ViewBag.dane = user;
            return View(user);
        }
```

In controller in select I have

> select new pracownikModel{p.Login, d.imie})

and I cant add

> uzytkownik = p.Login, imie = d.imie

because insted uzytkownik and imie i have LoginModel or uzytkonikModel.

I have

> select new **pracownikModel**{...}

and I have error:

> Cannot initialize type 'Restauracja.Models.pracownikModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've changed to use an anonymous object so the view doesn't know what type it is and defaults to the `object` type.  You could use `dynamic` instead of `var` or you could select into a class with the same properties as the anonymous object in which case it would be able to determine the type and know that it had those properties.

```
    @foreach (dynamic pr in ViewBag.dane)
    {
        <div>Login: @pr.Login</div>

          <div>Imie: @pr.imie</div> 

    }
```

Or

```
public ActionResult detail(int LoginID)
{
    var user = (from p in baza.Logowanies
                join d in baza.uzytkowniks on p.LoginID equals d.LoginID 
                where LoginID == p.LoginID
                select new LoginModel
                {
                    Login = p.Login,
                    Haslo = p.Haslo,
                    ...
                }).ToList();
    ViewBag.dane = user;
    return View();
}
```

With the model class

```
public class LoginModel
{
      public string Login { get; set; }
      public string Haslo { get; set; }
      ...
}
```

Any reason why you're not using a view model rather than setting data on the ViewBag?

Action

```
    ...
    return View( user );
}
```

View

```
@model LoginModel

...

     @foreach (dynamic pr in Model)
     {
        <div>Login: @pr.Login</div>

         <div>Imie: @pr.imie</div> 

     }
```

Comment: I try do as you wrote... but something is wrong... I edited my first question post.

Comment: You have to use the property initializer syntax.  `new pracownikModel{ nawisko = p.Login, imie = d.imie }` -- assuming I have your properties right.

Comment: I did how you sad but a still have a error:
`'Restauracja.Models.pracownikModel' does not contain a definition for 'nazwisko'`
`'Restauracja.Models.pracownikModel' does not contain a definition for 'imie'`

Comment: I see, you've split it into two models.  I suggest that you flatten it out so that the individual properties are represented in pracownikModel and assignment as I showed you in my comment. If you need to have a nested model, then try assigning the properties to the nested models properties, i.e., `new pracownikModel { Login.Haslo = p.Login.Haslo, ...,  uzytkownikModel.imie = p.imie }`